# Why href encode parameters in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, href, location-href

I have this issue that started recently on Safari, where my href gets encoded or some sort of changes occurs when navigating to that location.

Didn't happen yesterday or days before. On Chrome works fine.

Sample code here

```
href="https://website.com/my-next-page.html?url=https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MYPAYPALBUTTONID"
```

It used to take me to **my-next-page.html** where I was able to grab the url parameter exactly as I was passed.

Now my destination location.href looks like this

```
https://website.com/my-next-page.html?url=https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr&_gl=1*45ern0q*_ga*YW1wWxWHBTRkkFGJT4TmlHOFE.
```

Any suggestions why this started to happen?

Comment: What (HTTP headers) does `https://website.com/my-next-page.html` return?

Comment: It loads the website, however, the URL in the Safari browser is distorted.. I just researched the _gl that I see being added. This is something from Google analytics I believe that I've added probably. Gotta check on that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @BrittK Loads *which* website? Is there a redirect? What does the js in the page do?

Comment: You might want to try proper [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of the `url` parameter: `my-next-page.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com%2Fcgi-bin%2Fwebscr%3Fcmd%3D_s-xclick%26hosted_button_id%3DMYPAYPALBUTTONID`. If any script (including google analytics) messes with the url, not using `?` twice will help it being parsed correctly.

Comment: Yes, there is a redirect happening properly. I don't know why Google is appending this _gl tag. I can't find a way to ignore whatever Google Analytics does.

The encoding you've mentioned is a good idea, however, this will require a change across 50+ pages, that's why I'm trying to get rid of _gl messing up the URL